# Product depencencies: trigger reinstallation

Tags: plone, dependency-management

I'm developing a product for Plone, say `foo.core`. Besides that core product, there are also several related products. like `foo.optional`. These releated products may be available in the instance and if they are available they may be installed (in other words: I cannot assume the code is available or, if it is, should be used).

These related products may override settings made by `foo.core` (e.g. in a Property Sheet). This works fine, but if I reinstall `foo.core`, the default settings are back. What I'd want is to somehow automatically reinstall `foo.optional` when `foo.core` is reinstalled in the QuickInstaller.

The solutions I could come up with are:

- When `foo.optional` is installed, it
  registers itself with `foo.core`. The
  latter, `foo.core`, will handle the
  reinstallation of all registered
  products when the core package is
  reinstalled.
- The `foo.core` package
  triggers an event which other
  packages, like `foo.optional`, can
  listen for. An event handler will
  then trigger the reinstall of
  `foo.optional`.
- Make sure that `foo.core`
  doesn't overwrite any settings that
  may have been customized later by
  other products.

Perhaps there are more alternatives? What would be the 'Plonish' approach?

**Edit:** I know that using upgrade steps might be better than reinstalling the product. However IMHO the problem remains the same: the Generic Setup profile used for the upgrade step might have a setting that is modified in the Generic Setup profile for the `foo.optional` package.

So using upgrade steps makes my problem even harder: how should I determine whether the upgrade step of `foo.core` means `foo.optional` should be reinstalled/upgraded? (The assumption is still that `foo.core` in principle does not know about `foo.optional`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to your problem is much easier than what you propose:

We do NOT reinstall products like we did in the past when the product is updated. Reinstalling a product will cause your generic setup profile to be reapplied which is why you get your settings overwritten.

Instead you now provide upgrade steps. For instance if you change your profile version from 2 to 3 then you would have:

```xml
<genericsetup:upgradeStep
  title="Upgrade foo.core from revision 2 to 3"
  description="Adds stuff"
  source="2"
  destination="3"
  handler="foo.core.upgrades.two_to_three.addStuff"
  sortkey="1"
  profile="foo.core:default"
  />
```

Inside the upgrade step you can do what you like, even re-run individual import steps.

If your product upgrade does not involve changing the GS profile, do not increment the version in metadata.xml. In that case you obviously don't need an upgrade step either.

Comment: Granted, upgrade steps may be better than reinstalling the whole product. The chance of overriding the setting is smaller (not the complete profile is applied), but the problem remains the same: the profile of foo.core contains a setting which is overridden by the profile of foo.optional.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the complication. Why can't your upgrade step simply not overwrite the setting? It certainly exists (since the product is installed) and if it has been overwritten that's fine. If you do insist on running the import step, you can always provide purge=False to the setting.

Comment: And remember GS is meant to be the one-time configuration that is done well, once. Subsequent changes should be handled by upgrade steps.

Comment: Trivial example: the foo.core GS profile set the localTimeFormat to "%B %d, %Y". In the upgrade step foo.core sets the localTimeFormat back to Plone default: "%b %d, %Y". However, in foo.optional the localTimeFormat is set to "%Y-%m-%d". Just running the upgrade step for foo.core sets the format to the 'wrong' setting. So whenever foo.core is reinstalled/updated I need to trigger something to get the foo.optional settings back.

Comment: BTW I'm not trying to be stubborn here. I'm just not sure whether my problem isn't clear or my approach of handling these kind of dependencies and upgrades is wrong.

Comment: It seems to me that the way you try to solve your problem is on the wrong direction. You want your foo.core to be independent of foo.optional and yet to be aware of what foo.optional does. While I still think this is the wrong approach, you could go that way by means of registering different upgrade steps depending on whether foo.optional is installed. You can do that by wrapping the zcml registration in a <configure zcml:condition="installed foo.optional">. Again this sounds so very wrong, but hey if that's what you want that's what you get.

Comment: Thanks for your responses ggozad. I certainly agree that your last solution sounds wrong, indicating that my approach is wrong. The problem is subtly different though: I don't need foo.core to be aware of what foo.optional does, I want to foo.optional to be aware of any changes in foo.core that need to be overridden (again). Having said that, you got me to rethink my approach. Thanks again for your effort!

Comment: Glad to help, I think that rethinking your approach is the best thing in this case.

Comment: I realised that this is indeed the right approach, so as far as I'm concerned this is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are making things much harder on yourself by involving Plone's add-on installation story (which is complicated by "old" and "new" technologies living side by side). I would take a step back and think more about the plugin system you are trying to design/implement, and avoid including Plone until you absolutely have to [1].

You also might consider using entry points to implement at least a portion of the plugin system:

- http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Using+Entry+Points+to+Write+Plugins

[1] Assuming Plone is a strict requirement and that you are building a content-management-driven application, else you should probably be using Django or Pyramid

Comment: Plone is indeed a requirement. Not sure yet if entry points can help here (due to the existing architecture), but I'll definitely investigate that approach. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

Install/reinstall doesn't make sens in the context of an add-on. The vocabulary has been change to activate/unactivate but it is not again enough to understand the situation.

You have a 'setup' where you apply a configuration profile. Apply again and again a configuration profile doesn't make anything except broke existing configurations.

This is why every body will reply to this question by use upgrade step. We don't trigger profile on reinstall, we upgrade add-ons when the setup profile has some changes.

So if you are in a case where settings added by foo.core are changed by foo.optional you can do the following.

With the new plone.registry you can add a handler to the IRecord  related events:

- add
- edit
- remove

Consider the documentation:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.registry

I have done some code related to this where I want to rebuild css registry when some settings has been changed:

https://github.com/collective/collective.jqueryuithememanager/blob/master/collective/jqueryuithememanager/registry.py

Comment: I did not know plone.registry yet, thanks! It looks like this could also be a way to go for me.

Comment: your welcome. plone.registry is the brand new way to store configurations.